# A list of topics in measure theory helpful for studying functional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

I have learned some basic measure theory as covered in the first chapter of Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, which includes the construction of Lebesgue integral (from simple functions to bounded to positive to integrable ones), as well as some basic properties such as Fatou's Lemma, monotone convergence theorem, dominated convergence theorem, the Fubini theorem, etc.

> I will be officially taking Real Analysis (measure theory), next year. However, as sometimes functional analysis turns out to be sometimes illuminating for my undergraduate research in mathematical optimization, I want to have a basic pass through the most fundamental concepts of functional analysis.

I have read some posts here stating that it's possible to learn functional analysis before measure theory, but the other order is preferred due to the need for integration. Since I don't have much time nor want to stumble upon something that requires measure theory, does anyone has some recommendation on a list of topics or theorems that might be needed for a basic read on functional analysis? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have some basic background in general topology.

Comment: [**Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471504599) by Erwin Kreyszig (1978; .pdf file [here](https://physics.bme.hu/sites/physics.bme.hu/files/users/BMETE15AF53_kov/Kreyszig%20-%20Introductory%20Functional%20Analysis%20with%20Applications%20(1).pdf)) does not require any measure theory background.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for sharing. Do you think this book (or maybe other functional analysis books that do not require much measure theory) can develop the theory well and in full or does it really matter? I really don't mind learning a bit more measure theory, if that makes the theory more elegant.

Comment: I also found [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Friendly-Functional-Essential-Textbooks-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B06ZYTJTBL/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=2GU9C3OQMHSGI&keywords=A+friendly+introduction+to+functional+analysis&qid=1690396921&s=books&sprefix=a+friendly+introduction+to+functional+analysis%2Cstripbooks%2C1549&sr=1-2-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&psc=1), that also doesn't seem to require measure theory. Is this worth reading, or would it be better to learn some measure theory and read a more traditional functional analysis textbook?

Comment: Kreyszig's book has two short chapters (I think 5 and 6) dealing with the application to optimization

Comment: @DavidRaveh That's nice. I'll read about it then. Thank you.

Comment: Many applications of the Hahn-Banach theorem (arguably, the central result of functional analysis) require knowledge of the dual space. The most important representation theorem of Riesz identifies the dual of the space $C(K)$ of continuous functions on a compact (metrizable, say, which is good enough in most cases) with the space of signed Borel measures on $K$.